# Display Suite show results from blocks

Tags: 7, display-suite

I am using Display Suite search as default search module. Is there a way to add the contents of blocks to the search results?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the Display Suite extras module you can create a display suite field that contains a block. It's included in the DS module you just have to enable it.

Comment: I see that on the Fields tab I can Add a block field. But that doesn't sound like it will do what I need. I just want text that exists in the body of a block to show up in the search results. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you should add your content as nodes but expose them as a block with the module node_block? This way you can both index the content and use it as a block...